# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the VendorsService (?). Please verify whether [0] argument is available in thecurrent context

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am new to nest js and typescript also. Thanks in advance.

I am getting this error continuously.

**Nest can't resolve dependencies of the VendorsService (?). Please verify whether [0] argument is available in thecurrent context.**

Here is the code

**App module**

```
@Module({
  imports: [ UsersModule, VendorsModule],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

**controller**

```
@Controller()
export class VendorsController {
    constructor(private readonly vendorService: VendorsService){}
@Post()
async create(@Body() createVendorDTO: CreateVendorDTO){
    this.vendorService.create(createVendorDTO);
}

@Get()
async findAll(): Promise<Vendor[]>{
    return this.vendorService.findAll();
}
}
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class VendorsService {

    constructor(@Inject('VendorModelToken') private readonly vendorModel: Model<Vendor>) {}

    async create(createVendorDTO: CreateVendorDTO): Promise<Vendor>{
        const createdVendor = new this.vendorModel(createVendorDTO);
        return await createdVendor.save();
    }
    async findAll(): Promise<Vendor[]>{
        return await this.vendorModel.find().exec();
    }
}
```

**provider**

```
export const usersProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'VendorModelToken',
    useFactory: (connection: Connection) => connection.model('Vendor', VendorSchema),
    inject: ['DbConnectionToken'],
  },
];
```

**Module**

```
@Module({
  providers: [VendorsService],
  controllers: [VendorsController],
})
export class VendorsModule {}
```

Comment: If you are using Nestjs 5 then check this issue and add your name in the comments.  https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/723

Answer (score 1):

VendorsModule sould declare your provider (usersProviders) in its `providers`, otherwise Nestjs will never be able to inject it into your service.

Unless you wanted to declare it with UsersModule (I guess you did); in that case, UsersModule also needs it in its `exports` so it's made visible to other modules importing UsersModule.

It's either `VendorsModule`: usersProviders in `providers`,

**Or** `UsersModule`: usersProviders in both `providers` and `exports`

Comment: Op should mark this as correct. This worked for me!